# python how to bind control+shift+0(Zero)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried a couple of combos like Control-Shift-0, Control-), Control-Shift-Key-0, but none of them works.

This link https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/events-names seems to tell me to use Control-Shift-Key-0 but it's not working. I don't have problems with other bindings of mine(like Control-0) and this is how I bind it.

```
self.master.bind('<Control-Shift-Key-0>', lambda event: self.clear(0))
```

I am 100% percent sure the function works properly because I also put it in the menu bar and it works.

I don't have to use this key binding but it would be helpful to know how to do it.

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about the letter "O" or the number zero?

Comment: @BryanOakley Zero.

Comment: On my keyboard, shift-zero on the main part of the keyboard is a right parenthesis. Is that what you're trying to bind to?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am trying to bind Control-Shift-0. Since right parenthesis is shift-zero on my keyboard as well, I have also tried Control-) but failed.

Comment: On my computer, the tkinter's keysym for ) is parenright, so to bind Control-) I need to use `'<Control-parenright>'`.

Comment: @j_4321 Sadly not working.

Comment: On Windows, ctrl-shift-0 is a built-in function - used for switching input methods, I think.  It's never going to reach your program.

Comment: @jasonharper I guess you are right. I can do Ctrl-Shift-1 but not 0 on my computer.